# How do I find the best dimensions to a house shape to maximize area?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization, quadratics

For an upcoming grade 11 test, there is this question i don't understand. Here are the requirements:
The perimeter is a maximum of $60$ cm.

The question wants me to come up with the dimensions of this shape:
[image: The shape's appearance]

I cannot change the fact that there are two sets of equal side, so there are 2 variables that need to be found. I am stuck, i don't know what to do. I have the correct answer from my teacher but not the process. Answer $= 14.06$cm and $8.91$cm

Can someone please show me how to do this? My test starts on 2017-09-27.
If you answer it after that, it is still okay, hopefully others will learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Call $a$ the base of the shape, and $b$ its height. The perimeter $P$ is

$$
P = 3a + 2b ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ b = (P - 3a)/2 \tag{1}
$$

and its area is

$$
A = ab + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2 \tag{2}
$$

where the first term is the area of a rectangle, whereas the second one is the area of an equilateral triangle of side $a$.

After you replace (2) in (1) you get

$$
A = \frac{1}{4} a ((-6 + \sqrt{3}) a + 2 P) = \frac{1}{4} (\sqrt{3} - 6) \left(\frac{P}{\sqrt{3} - 6} + a\right)^2 - \frac{P^2}{4 (\sqrt{3} - 6)} \tag{3}
$$

The first term is negative, the second is positive, so the maximum of the area is reached when the first term is zero, and that happens when

$$
a = \frac{P}{6 -\sqrt{3}} \tag{4}
$$

replacing in (1) you can get the value of $b$

$$
b= \frac{1}{22} (5 - \sqrt{3}) P \tag{5}
$$

Comment: i understand (1), but how did you get to (2) with those two equations?  is (2) the area of a square added by area of a triangle? Then after that i get completely lost. Are you talking about substituting?

Comment: @A.Hoss Eq. (2) is the area of the rectangle plus the area of the triangle. Replace the value of $b$ into this equation and simplify. Then complete the squares and you get to Eq. (3)

Comment: Okay, when i get to (3), do you get to (4) by simplifying (3)? I am not too good at math, so when i try to learn things, it works best if i see all the steps. like the process of getting from (2) to (3), and (3) to (4) and so on. Also for P, i can replace it with 60 in steps (3) (4) (5)?

Comment: I will reply later, probably 8+ hours from now, i will attempt it later as it is quite late for me, 11:50 as i type this comment, and i will have to wake up early for school. I would be very happy if you added in more steps in between the ones you had posted. It will help me understand a lot better.

Comment: @A.Hoss From As I said, from (3) to (4) you use this argument: $A$ is the sum of two terms $A = -{\rm Term}_1 + {\rm Term}_2$, where  ${\rm Term}_2$ is just a number, and ${\rm Term}_1$ depends on $a$. Since you want to maximize the area, you have to reduce the effect of the first term, which is subtracting.  The bet thing you can do is to set to zero ${\rm Term}_1 = 0$, and from here you get a value of $a$. And to answer your other question, yes, you can replace $P=60$

Comment: Is there another way, i just don't understand (3) (4) (5). If i sub in the "b" equation from (1) into (2), i don't know how to get (3) from there. Please, is there any other method of doing this?  I am good at completing the square, and factoring, not that great at using radicals. Is there a different method that better suits my skills?

Comment: @A.Hoss if you are comfortable with factoring and completing squares, but the problem is the radicals, then just use a calculator, and follow all the steps above